Curve generated by bended wood
Well I'm not an expert in physics so I'm sorry if this question is very trivial under some physical theory I don't know, but my question is:
What curve is generated by the act of bending a flat object. For instance a wooden plank or a metal pipe. What would be the curve that I see from side view when looking at such phenomena? And how should I even think about such thing as bending? Is there a way to phrase it in terms of Newtonian mechanics? Can a closed formula for the curves be extracted from the model of the block in Newtonian mechanics?

There's no unique answer for this question. It will depend on the material. I think that you'd need to provide more details to get a reasonable answer. Your top question does specify wood (still probably depends on details of the specific wood) but the main body references other materials completely.

Yes that's because I wanted an answer specifically for wood. I said the other things thinking if it would be possible to make a generalized formula that depends on numeral values of the solid such as density or I don't know what but apparently you say it depends on more. My physics teacher told me that wood is just binded fibers and that this fact affects the shape of the bend but this still doesn't give me an answer nor to wood or to let's say a metal pipe.

Just to give an idea that it may depend on a lot more - To weave a basket, you usually soak the wood to make it pliable during the weave stage.  Then it dries and holds its shape when it dries.

Ok but the thing is I don't know which cases are solvable or like are not to hard to model with Newtonian physics. So I don't really know which questions to ask. Can you give me an example of a substance in conditions which allows it to be simply modeled in that sense?

See my answer below for a detailed process to work things like this out. The biggest things it depends on is whether or not the material is elastically deforming (bending, but if you let go, it goes back to its orginal shape), or plastically deforming (permanently changing shape). If it's elastic bending, you can use formulas like the above and the process I describe in my answer, and you use the modulus of elasticity to model the stiffness of the material. ...

... For wood, going with the grain or against the grain can change that modulus of elasticity value. Against the grain is far weaker and is often very discouraged in structural design.

What you are looking for is the beam deflection curve of a rigid body. If you want a specific instance, Googling "beam deflection tables" will often give you the example you want. However, for more complex loading or if you want to do it yourself, here's how:
Step 1: Identify all of the forces acting on the object. This method only works for static (non-moving objects), so using the sums of forces and moments on the object will allow you to solve for any support reactions. Note that this only works if the structure is statically determinate and stable - in other words, there aren't too many supports or too few. If you have too few supports, it's unstable and the structure will collapse with any small changes, including the ones bending would cause (imagine balancing a pencil on another pencil, point to point - it's possible, but only in theory. If either bends or moves a little, it collapses). If you have too many, you can't solve it only using sum of forces or moments - there's too many unknowns. There are a lot of methods to solve these statically indeterminate, but they're more complicated.
Step 2: Determine the function for the internal shear forces across the beam. This can be done using equations or a graph, whichever is easier. You'll need a new equation for each section which has a different condition on it (e.g. break it into sections at each change in applied forces or moments and at supports or hinges) An equation for a cantilever beam with a fixed end and with force F on its free end is $V(x)=F$.
Step 3: Integrate the shear function to get the moment function (don't forget any +c, your constant applied or reaction moments). Again, this can be done graphically, analytically, or numerically. For our cantilver above, this is $M(x)=Fx+c$, where c is the moment at the support ($F*l$, where l is the length of the beam), so $M(x)=Fx+Fl$.
Step 4: The integral of the moment function is proportional to the angle of deflection function, with a scale factor of $E*I$, where E is the stiffness of the material (its Young's modulus or modulus of elasticity) and I is the moment of inertia for the cross section of the beam. For our example, $\theta(x)=(Fx^2/2+Flx+c)/EI$. c in this case is the deflection angle at the wall, which for our case is 0, so $\theta(x)=(Fx^2/2+Flx)/EI$.
Step 5: The integral of the angle function is the deflection curve, what we are looking for. In our case, this is $\delta(x)=(Fx^3/6+Flx^2/2+c)/EI$. c in this case is the deflection at the wall, which is 0, so our final equation is $\delta(x)=(Fx^3/6+Flx^2/2+c)/EI$.
Step 6: In most cases, you won't be immediately able to determine the +c's of different sections. In that case, use boundary or continuity conditions to solve for it. For instance, in this case, for boundary conditions, we knew that the deflection at a support is 0, and the angle at a fixed support like a wall is 0. If you have separate sections, continuity says that the deflection at the point where they touch has to be the same, as does the angle if there's no hinge there.
For our example, with a little rearranging of terms, we get the usual cantilver deflection formula: $\delta(x)=-Fx^2*(3L-x)/6EI$.
Note that this only works if the material is still elastically bending, not plastically deforming or buckling. It can also be inaccurate if you are looking right at the supports, depending on your assumptions: above, I assumed the wall was prefectly rigid and so the beam couldn't bend or move at the wall. This is only true for a very, very stiff connection. The more complicated the problem or the closer to a support you are, the more the basic assumptions have to be modified to fix things like that.

The physics you are looking for is called "Beam theory". It is essentially Newton's laws applied to beam shaped objects that have some elasticity. In some cases (small bending, "normal enough" material) you can get explicit formulas for the amount of deflection away as a function of the position down the length of the object.

For example, for a "cantilevered" beam that is fixed (no pivoting or motion) at one end, with a constant force applied at the end, the amount of deflection as a function of the distance $x$ down the beam will be
$$\delta(x)= \frac{F}{6EI}(3L-x) x^2$$
Where $E$ is the modulus of elasticity, and $I$ is the area moment of the beam's cross section. This should be the case for any material that has a well-defined modulus of elasticity and for forces that do not cause any permanent deformation of the beam.

Thank you Mike, can you give me an example of a material that can be modeled by Newtonian physics and closed curve formulae it gives?

Ok so I have a formula for deflection, so I should probably do some ΣF=0 to find the behavior of the curve at a balanced point. Would it give me a differential equation that models the curve?

Yes, there is a differential equation that can be derived from Newton's laws and the theory of elasticity of continuous materials to find the deflection

I don't want to find the deflection with a differential equation, I want to find the shape that the beam forms into.

The shape that the beam forms into can be found from the differential equation, boundary conditions, and how you are bending the beam. The exact shape is going to depend on those parameters.
